# The view shop.views.product_list didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, django-views, return, httpresponse

Here is my code , I am getting same error again and again. I dont know whats wrong here.

```
category = None
categories = Category.objects.all()
products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
if  category_slug:
    category = get_object_or_404(Category,  slug=category_slug)
    products = products.filter(category=category)
    return  render(request,'templates/shop/product/list.html',{'category':category,'categories':categories,'products':products})
```

Comment: If the if case is false your view does not return anything. Take care of this with an else statement.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the return position. You're returning every time and it needs to complete the cycle before that happens.
The if and return statements should be on the same line/position as this:

```
    category =None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category=get_object_or_404(Category, 
                                    slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request, 'product/list.html',
                    {'category': category,
                    'categories':categories,
                    'products': products})
```